# Overlapping jquery mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a card list.
The li elements inside the card list has both mouseenter and mouseleave event.

```
mouseenterCard: function(index) {
    var nOnRight = index+2;
    var n = index+1;

    if (n!=1) {
        $('#cards-list li:nth-child('+n.toString()+')').animate({'margin-left': '30px'},
                                                                 "fast",
                                                                 function() {

                                                                 });
    }
    $('#cards-list li:nth-child('+nOnRight.toString()+')').animate({'margin-left': '30px'},
                                                                   "fast");
},
mouseleaveCard: function(index) {
    var nOnRight = index+2;
    var n = index+1;
    if (n!=1) {
        $('#cards-list li:nth-child('+n.toString()+')').animate({'margin-left': marginLeft.toString()+'px'},
                                                                 "fast",
                                                                 function() {

                                                                 });
    }
    $('#cards-list li:nth-child('+nOnRight.toString()+')').animate({'margin-left': marginLeft.toString()+'px'},
                                                                   "fast");
}

$('#cards-list').on('mouseenter', 'li' ,function(e){
    CardList.getInstance().mouseenterCard($(this).index());
});

$('#cards-list').on('mouseleave', 'li' ,function(e){
    CardList.getInstance().mouseleaveCard($(this).index());
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://www.catoyeung.com/showcase/cards.php)
As you swap between two elements quickly, the li elements behave weird.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The animation gets queued as you move over the same element multiple times.  You have to stop the animation with either `.stop` or `.finish` (latter ends the animation instantly):

```
$('#cards-list li:nth-child('+nOnRight.toString()+')').stop().animate(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try debouncing/throttling the events.
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

If You have running animations, use .stop() on the mouseleave event to break the animation